# Websphere MDB activation with alternative deployment descriptor "<alt-dd>"

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, ejb-3.1, websphere-8

I'm trying to deploy an MDB with an alternative deployment descriptor located in my EAR in my Websphere 8.5 (Java EE specification).  Example:

```
<module>
  <ejb>arq_frameworkEJB.jar</ejb>
  <alt-dd>dds/ejb-jar.xml</alt-dd>
</module>
```

The problem is the WAS EJB container is complaining about not finding the required binding file *ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml* (this binding is required to activate the MDB). The error says:

> com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBConfigurationException: REQUIRED_BINDING_NOT_FOUND for MDB: arqMDB

I've tried multiple locations for this file (inside the arq_frameworkEJB.jar), inside the EARs META-INF folder, but it doesn't work.  I've searched on internet, but haven't found any documentation neither mention about where this file is supposed to be.

Comment: Have you tried placing the ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml relative to the ejb-jar.xml file (i.e., in the dds folder)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

1. Activate "trace" mode in WAS.
2. Open "trace.log" and check where is WAS looking for alternative binding file.

trace.log:

> [20/03/14 9:19:08:557 CET] 00000046 bindext       3
>   com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.EARFileImpl
>   initializeModuleExtensions Alternate Bindings URI:
>   [ALT-INF/arq_frameworkEJB.jar/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml]

Try this configuration:

```
ALT-INF/ejb-jar.xml
ALT-INF/arq_frameworkEJB.jar/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml
```

Thats works!

Answer (score -1):

The ejb binding file should be placed in ejb-module/META-INF in ejb project. For web project it should be in WEB-INF/. It takes the same location as ejb-jar.xml.